# Solutions to $x^2 + y^3 = z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The question I was given: Find all solutions to $x^2 + y^3 = z^2$ in which x,y, and z are pairwise relatively prime and y is even.
What I have so far: If $y$ is even then the equation becomes $x^2+8*b^3=z^2$ where b is the integer $y/2$ and $x$ and $z$ must be odd.  I don't know if I should do anything mod 8 or how to approach this problem.

Comment: I'd write $y^3=z^2-x^2$ since both sides factor.

Comment: Note that every number not $\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ can be written as the difference of $2$ squares.  If $y$ is odd, for example, then you could take $(x,y,z)=\left(\frac {y^3+1}2,y,\frac {y^3-1}2\right)$.

Comment: This mentions the equation [Solvability of the Diophantine equation $x^{2} - y^{2} = 4z^{n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254193/solvability-of-the-diophantine-equation-x2-y2-4zn). Also here an answer gives some parametric solutions [Find all pairs of positive integers $(x,y)$ such that $x^2-y^2=a^3$ and $x^3-y^3=b^2$ for integral $a, b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53292/find-all-pairs-of-positive-integers-x-y-such-that-x2-y2-a3-and-x3-y3)

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below;

$x^2 + y^3 = z^2$

Since variable $(y)$ is required to be even & comment

given by "Lulu" gives rational solution of $(x,z)$ 
instead of integer solution,

another solution is given below:

$(x,y,z)= ((2k^2-k),(2k),(2k^2+k))$

For $k=2$ we get $(x,y,z)=(6,4,10)$